# converting string to map in dart

Tags: dart, flutter

I wanted to convert a string to map.

```
String value = "{first_name : fname,last_name : lname,gender : male, location : { state : state, country : country, place : place} }"
```

into

```
Map = {
first_name : fname,
last_name : lname,
gender : male,
location = {
  state : state, 
  country : country, 
  place : place
 }
}
```

How do I convert the string into a `map<String, dynamic>` where the value consists of string, int, object, and boolean?

I wanted to save the string to a file and obtain the data from the file.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

That's not possible.

If you can change the string to valid JSON, you can use

```
import 'dart:convert';
...
Map valueMap = json.decode(value);
// or
Map valueMap = jsonDecode(value);
```

The string would need to look like

```
{"first_name" : "fname","last_name" : "lname","gender" : "male", "location" : { "state" : "state", "country" : "country", "place" : "place"} }
```

Comment: If you are saving an existing map, you can likely convert that map to a valid JSON string using `json.encode`, then it will parse back correctly using `json.decode`.

Comment: how can i covert this type of string to map    [{type: Input, title: Hi Group, placeholder: Hi Group flutter, response: fgggh}, {type: Password, title: Password, response: vvvvv}, {type: Email, title: Email test, placeholder: hola a todos, response: cccvc}, {type: TareaText, title: TareaText test, placeholder: hola a todos, response: vvvvv}]

Comment: What you posted is not JSON. In JSON all keys and string values would need quotes. If it were valid JSON you could use `var decoded = json.decode(yourString); var map = Map.fromIterable(decoded, key: (e) => e.keys.first, value: (e) => e.values.first);` (not tested). See also https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/Map/Map.fromIterable.html

Answer (score 45):

You would have to change the way you create the string.

I'm guessing you are creating the string using the `yourMap.toString()` method. You should rather use `json.encode(yourMap)`, which converts your map to valid JSON, which you can the parse with `json.decode(yourString)`.

Comment: Map insides of Map insides of Map insides of Object(Map). Thanks for reminding me of this

Comment: this is usefull

Answer (score 7):

create two objects

```
class User {
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final String gender;
  final location;

  User({
    this.firstName,
    this.lastName,
    this.gender,
    this.location,
  });

  User.fromJson(Map json)
      : firstName = json['firstName'],
        lastName = json['lastName'],
        gender = json['gender'],
        location = Location.fromJson(json['location']);
}

class Location {
  final String state;
  final String country;
  final String place;

  Location({
    this.state,
    this.country,
    this.place,
  });

  Location.fromJson(Map json)
      : state = json['state'],
        country = json['country'],
        place = json['place'];
}
```

then use it like this

```
var user = User.fromJson(value);
print(user.firstName);
```

or convert it to list like this

```
var user = User.fromJson(value).toList();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution, I was getting error because I was using **.toString** instead of **jsonEncode**

Answer (score 5):

you can do like this ->

import 'dart:convert';
...

> if your data like this  **
> {'bus1':'100Tk','bus2':'150TK','bus3':'200TK'}

**;

then you can do like this ->

```
Map valueMap = json.decode(value);
```

// or

```
Map valueMap = jsonDecode(value);
```

> **or if like this ->var data = {'1':'100TK','2':'200TK','3':'300TK'};**

```
var dataSp = data.split(',');
Map<String,String> mapData = Map();
dataSp.forEach((element) => mapData[element.split(':')[0]] = element.split(':')[1]);
```

> Note: Map first value was Int that's why I did that.

Answer (score 4):

Make a [wrapper class](https://github.com/acinonyxjubatus/flyflutter_fast_start/blob/master/lib/model/placemark_local.dart) for the location where you define the methods `fromMap`, `toMap`

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, that's not possible.

But i have workaround to fix that.

- Remove space in ur invalid json
- Fix ur invalid string json to valid string json
- Convert valid string json to map

Here's the full code for above process:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  String value = "{first_name : fname,last_name : lname,gender : male, location : { state : state, country : country, place : place} }";
  
  String jsonString = _convertToJsonStringQuotes(raw: value);
  print("Test 1: $jsonString");
  
  final Map<dynamic, dynamic> result = json.decode(jsonString);
  print('Test 2: $result');
}


String _convertToJsonStringQuotes({required String raw}) {
    /// remove space
    String jsonString = raw.replaceAll(" ", "");

    /// add quotes to json string
    jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll('{', '{"');
    jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll(':', '": "');
    jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll(',', '", "');
    jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll('}', '"}');

    /// remove quotes on object json string
    jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll('"{"', '{"');
    jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll('"}"', '"}');

    /// remove quotes on array json string
    jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll('"[{', '[{');
    jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll('}]"', '}]');

    return jsonString;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
To convert a string into a map<String, dynamic>, you can use the
```

following code:

```
String value = "{first_name : fname,last_name : lname,gender : male, location : { state : state, country : country, place : place} }";
         String result = value
           .replaceAll("{","{\"")
           .replaceAll("}","\"}")
           .replaceAll(":","\":\"")
           .replaceAll(",","\",\"");
        print(result);
```

Here, we first replace the opening and closing curly braces with double quotes, and then replace the colons and commas with quotes to create a valid JSON string. Then, we use the jsonDecode method to convert the JSON string into a map.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to cast that string

Ok, lets use a complex model to cast:

```dart
final testMap = {
  'userName': 'Igor',
  'age': 22,
  'totalCash': 138.57,
  'isMale:': true,
  'userStatus': {
    'isUserActive': true,
    'isAPremiumUser': false,
  },
  'userTags': ['Flutter Developer', 'Proactive', 'Clean code'],
  'userCourses': [
    {
      'title': 'How to use TDD in flutter',
      'finished': false,
      'coursePercentage': 47.4,
      'buyDate': '1969-07-20T20:18:04.000Z',
      'courseTag': ['New', 'Popular'],
      'courseDetails': null,
    },
    {
      'title': 'Clean arquiteture in flutter',
      'finished': false,
      'coursePercentage': 20.8,
      'buyDate': '1969-07-20T20:18:04.000Z',
      'courseTag': ['New'],
      'courseDetails': {
        'teacherName': 'Tayler Mostoult',
        'totalSubscribers': 5402,
      },
    },
    {
      'title': 'Micro-frontends in flutter',
      'finished': true,
      'coursePercentage': 100.0,
      'buyDate': '1969-07-20T20:18:04.000Z',
      'courseTag': [],
      'courseDetails': {},
    },
  ]
};
```

Know, cast it to string:

```dart
final testMapInStringFormat = testMap.toString();
```

To convert this String to map, we can use:

```dart
// Decoded, back to map format
final Map response = _getJsonFromString(testMap.toString());
```

### The function that will effectively do the casting:

```
  Map<String, dynamic> _getJsonFromString(String rawText) {
    // Will find, for exemple, the text: "{isUserActive:"
    final regexMapKeyWithOpenBracket = RegExp('(?<={)(.*?):+');
    // Will find, for exemple, the text: ", userCourses:"
    final regexMapKeyWithCommaAndSpace = RegExp(r'(?<=, )([^\]]*?):');

    final regexOnlyKeyInLine = RegExp(r'^.+:$');

    final splitedSentences = rawText
        .replaceAllMapped(regexMapKeyWithCommaAndSpace,
            (Match match) => '\n${match.text.trim()}\n')
        .replaceAllMapped(regexMapKeyWithOpenBracket,
            (Match match) => '\n${match.text.trim()}\n')
        .replaceAll(RegExp(r'}(?=,|]|}|$|\s+)'), '\n}\n')
        .replaceAll(RegExp(r'(?<=(,|:|^|\[)\s?){'), '\n{\n')
        .replaceAll(RegExp('\\[\\s?\\]'), '\n[\n]\n')
        .replaceAll(RegExp('\\{\\s?\\}'), '\n{\n}\n')
        .replaceAll('[', '\n[\n')
        .replaceAll(']', '\n]\n')
        .replaceAll(',', '\n,\n')
        .split('\n')
      ..removeWhere((element) => element.replaceAll(' ', '').isEmpty);

    final List<String> correctLines = [];
    for (String line in splitedSentences) {
      final isMapKey = regexOnlyKeyInLine.hasMatch(line);

      if (isMapKey) {
        final lineWithoutFinalTwoDots = line.substring(0, line.length - 1);
        final lineWithQuaot = _putQuotationMarks(lineWithoutFinalTwoDots);

        correctLines.add('$lineWithQuaot:');
      } else {
        String l = line.trim();

        final hasCommaInFinal = l.endsWith(',') && l.length > 1;
        if (hasCommaInFinal) l = l.substring(0, l.length - 1);

        // If it falls in this else, it is a value of a key or a map structure
        final isNumber = double.tryParse(l) != null || int.tryParse(l) != null;
        final isBolean = l == 'false' || l == 'true';
        final isStructureCaracter =
            ['{', '}', '[', ']', ','].any((e) => e == l);
        final isNull = l == 'null';
        if (isStructureCaracter || isNumber || isBolean || isNull) {
          if (hasCommaInFinal) {
            correctLines.add('$l,');
          } else {
            correctLines.add(l);
          }
          continue;
        }

        // If you got to this point, i'm sure it's a value string, so lets add a double quote
        final lineWithQuaot = _putQuotationMarks(l);
        if (hasCommaInFinal) {
          correctLines.add('$lineWithQuaot,');
        } else {
          correctLines.add(lineWithQuaot);
        }
      }
    }

    final Map<String, dynamic> decoded = {};
    (jsonDecode(correctLines.join('')) as Map)
        .cast<String, dynamic>()
        .forEach((key, value) {
      decoded[key] = value;
    });

    return decoded;
  }

extension MatchExtension on Match {
  String get text => input.substring(start, end);
}

String _putQuotationMarks(String findedText) {
  if (!findedText.startsWith('\'') && !findedText.startsWith('"')) {
    findedText = findedText[0] + findedText.substring(1);
  }
  if (!findedText.endsWith('\'')) {
    final lastIndex = findedText.length - 1;
    findedText = findedText.substring(0, lastIndex) + findedText[lastIndex];
  }
  return '"$findedText"';
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use below method 
just pass String json data it will give Map data

```
jsonStringToMap(String data){
      List<String> str = data.replaceAll("{","").replaceAll("}","").replaceAll("\"","").replaceAll("'","").split(",");
      Map<String,dynamic> result = {};
      for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
        List<String> s = str[i].split(":");
        result.putIfAbsent(s[0].trim(), () => s[1].trim());
      }
      return result;
    }
```