# type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' in type cast Flutter realtime database

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]When i create a realtime database table, then i get the table datas, but i got and i changed the method and tried `Map data = snapshot.value as Map`

[image: HERE is THE ERROR]

```
    import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/ui/firebase_animated_list.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AmbobaDetals extends StatefulWidget {
  final double width;

  final EdgeInsets paddingForName;
  final EdgeInsets paddingForprice;
  final EdgeInsets paddingForstroke;
  final EdgeInsets paddingForunfildPrice;
  AmbobaDetals({
    super.key,
    required this.paddingForName,
    required this.paddingForprice,
    required this.paddingForstroke,
    required this.paddingForunfildPrice,
    required this.width,
  });

  @override
  State<AmbobaDetals> createState() => _AmbobaDetalsState();
}

class _AmbobaDetalsState extends State<AmbobaDetals> {
  Query dreamA = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('anboba');

  Widget listingOrder({required Map data}) => Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, bottom: 15),
      child: Container(
        child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
          Text(data['name']),
          // Text(data['adress']),
        ]),
      ));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SizedBox(
      height: double.infinity,
      child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
        query: dreamA,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
            Animation<double> animation, int index) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data =
              Map<String, dynamic>.from(snapshot.value as Map);
          return listingOrder(data: data);
        },
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

here is it

```
  "anboba": {
    "name": "ANBOBA",
    "price": 117,
    "stoke": "In stock",
    "unfild price": 1400
  },
  "drivers": {
    "2Y6gMoLreHgcyQRMSmhhN3zn09m2": {
      "email": "mohamhdffdfasdfed@gmail.com",
      "id": "2Y6gMoLreHgcyQRMSmhhN3zn09m2",
      "name": "mohamedasd sdahhhh"
    },
    "C2NawPLYJgVWBt5ckhawM87xuSJ3": {
      "email": "mohamhdffsddfddfased@gmail.com",
      "id": "C2NawPLYJgVWBt5ckhawM87xuSJ3",
      "name": "mohamedasd sda"
    },
    "eO5LVXmXCvaMtI10r3QzmkR4srJ2": {
      "email": "mohamhdffsddffdddfased@gmail.com",
      "id": "eO5LVXmXCvaMtI10r3QzmkR4srJ2",
      "name": "mohamedasd sda"
    },
    "hzucHzMeIqftErhGJEINEBkzOI82": {
      "email": "mohamed100397@gmail.com",
      "id": "hzucHzMeIqftErhGJEINEBkzOI82",
      "name": "mohamed"
    },
    "jUv2wGQtB5PZlJdVcyGnLdskW0w2": {
      "email": "mohamhdffdfased@gmail.com",
      "id": "jUv2wGQtB5PZlJdVcyGnLdskW0w2",
      "name": "mohamedasd sdahhhh"
    },
    "null": {
      "AjlVieBNXeaArW1BvESDQHlCTJB2": {
        "adress": "492F+JP4, Sheraton Al Matar, Cairo Governorate, Egypt",
        "age": "https://www.google.com/maps/search/30.0993217,31.3744967",
        "key": "AjlVieBNXeaArW1BvESDQHlCTJB2",
        "name": "AjlVieBNXeaArW1BvESDQHlCTJB2"
      }
    }
  },
  "finshed orders": {
    "2Y6gMoLreHgcyQRMSmhhN3zn09m2": {
      "AjlVieBNXeaArW1BvESDQHlCTJB2": {
        "adress": "3 Omar Ibn El-Khattab, Sheraton Al Matar, Cairo Governorate, Egypt",
        "age": "https://www.google.com/maps/search/30.0993217,31.3744967",
        "key": "AjlVieBNXeaArW1BvESDQHlCTJB2",
        "name": "AjlVieBNXeaArW1BvESDQHlCTJB2"
      }
    },
    "ILk7xyDa3aYfU7BKhIMK3gPO9Rp2": {
      "eeJ9AaueVpfPK2zG7joXc63pXXm1": {
        "adress": "Garcia & Amphitheater, Mountain View, California, United States",
        "age": "https://www.google.com/maps/search/37.4219983,-122.084",
        "key": "eeJ9AaueVpfPK2zG7joXc63pXXm1",
        "name": "eeJ9AaueVpfPK2zG7joXc63pXXm1"
      }
    }
  },
  "orders": {
    "2Y6gMoLreHgcyQRMSmhhN3zn09m2": {
      "AjlVieBNXeaArW1BvESDQHlCTJB2": {
        "adress": "3 Omar Ibn El-Khattab, Sheraton Al Matar, Cairo Governorate, Egypt",
        "age": "https://www.google.com/maps/search/30.0993217,31.3744967",
        "key": "AjlVieBNXeaArW1BvESDQHlCTJB2",
        "name": "AjlVieBNXeaArW1BvESDQHlCTJB2"
      }
    },
    "ILk7xyDa3aYfU7BKhIMK3gPO9Rp2": {
      "eeJ9AaueVpfPK2zG7joXc63pXXm1": {
        "adress": "Garcia & Amphitheater, Mountain View, California, United States",
        "age": "https://www.google.com/maps/search/37.4219983,-122.084",
        "key": "eeJ9AaueVpfPK2zG7joXc63pXXm1",
        "name": "eeJ9AaueVpfPK2zG7joXc63pXXm1"
      }
    }
  },
  "users": {
    "29wineAudEUQVWuAMGhVG4BwxRI3": {
      "email": "mohamedsaeed948@yahoo.com",
      "id": "29wineAudEUQVWuAMGhVG4BwxRI3",
      "name": "mohamed ashmawu"
    },
    "2IlB5okTH0UQaGKgZcJXl3KBQGU2": {
      "adress": "39XF+MMM, Sheraton Al Matar, Cairo Governorate, Egypt",
      "age": "https://www.google.com/maps/search/30.0995815,31.3744942",
      "key": "2IlB5okTH0UQaGKgZcJXl3KBQGU2",
      "name": "2IlB5okTH0UQaGKgZcJXl3KBQGU2"
    },
    "3jTJdBMZ7TZFzKOXwMpd6CIcB9B2": {
      "email": "mohamedsaeed98@yahoo.com",
      "id": "3jTJdBMZ7TZFzKOXwMpd6CIcB9B2",
      "name": "mohamed ashmawu"
    },
    "8NHp1Hn3sFdS9n3wfiKN4baJnBi2": {
      "email": "mohamedsaeedzezo@yahoo.com",
      "id": "8NHp1Hn3sFdS9n3wfiKN4baJnBi2",
      "name": "mohamed ashmawu"
    },
    "AjlVieBNXeaArW1BvESDQHlCTJB2": {
      "adress": "3 Omar Ibn El-Khattab, Sheraton Al Matar, Cairo Governorate, Egypt",
      "age": "https://www.google.com/maps/search/30.0993217,31.3744967",
      "key": "AjlVieBNXeaArW1BvESDQHlCTJB2",
      "name": "AjlVieBNXeaArW1BvESDQHlCTJB2"
    },
    "ILk7xyDa3aYfU7BKhIMK3gPO9Rp2": {
      "email": "saeed1234@gmail.com",
      "id": "ILk7xyDa3aYfU7BKhIMK3gPO9Rp2",
      "name": "mohamed"
    },
    "JbrFC0GcggPChc2Knwl0l9nCN1p2": {
      "email": "mohamedsaeed942ry7i8@yahoo.com",
      "id": "JbrFC0GcggPChc2Knwl0l9nCN1p2",
      "name": "mohamed ashmawu"
    },
    "aXWMaF8JEkYnfnOvJ6qjNpM9npl2": {
      "email": "mohamedahmaed@gmail.com",
      "id": "aXWMaF8JEkYnfnOvJ6qjNpM9npl2",
      "name": "mohaeefd fdasante"
    },
    "b7ninYWGEcRThTNjmZKakKYwR443": {
      "email": "saeed@gmail.com",
      "id": "b7ninYWGEcRThTNjmZKakKYwR443",
      "name": "mohamed"
    },
    "eeJ9AaueVpfPK2zG7joXc63pXXm1": {
      "email": "ashmawy803@gmail.com",
      "id": "eeJ9AaueVpfPK2zG7joXc63pXXm1",
      "name": "mohamed saeed ashmawy"
    }
  }
}
```

..................................................................................................

here is it dfdfdff dfdsfgdg dfgsgdsfgfdg gfdgfdgfdg
sdfsdf sfd sdf dsf sdfs ddfdf dfdf s  ffsfdfsdf sd sdf sdf ds fsdf sdf

Comment: It looks like you have a single `String` value at path `FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('anboba')` in your database. If you want to use that as a `Map`, you will have to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49651673/converting-string-to-map-in-dart

Comment: I want only to show the product price in the contaner

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: if you need any thing tell me

Comment: and i made it before and it woked

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the i made it and it responses with this erorr

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to read through all the documentation of the firebase package (I don't use firebase), but the Map.from function is designed to create a map from another map, which is evidently not what `snapshot.value` is. Since it seems like you're recieving a string, i'll assume it's json. You should instead use `Map<String, dynamic>.from(json.decode(snapshot.value));`

You will need to import `json` by putting `import 'dart:convert' show json;` at the top of your file.

Comment: ` Map<String, dynamic> data =
              Map<String, dynamic>.from(json.decode(snapshot.value));`

Comment: this is giving erorr in snapshot.value

Answer (score 0):

Your `anboba` node contains a single element with a number of properties (name, price, etc). When you use that in a `FirebaseAnimatedList`, your `itemBuilder` gets called with a `snapshot` being **one individual property** each time.

So `snapshot.value` is a single value each time your `itemBuilder` gets called. The first time, it'll be `"ANBOBA"`, the second call, it's `117`, etc.

---

You are trying to cast that single value to a `Map` here:

```
Map<String, dynamic>.from(snapshot.value as Map)
```

And that won't work, because the single value **isn't a map**.

---

You commented that you did this before and it worked. My best guess is that you then used this approach on a data structure like the one you have under `drivers`. There you have a **list of child elements**, each of which has a number of properties.

When you use `FirebaseAnimatedList` on *that*, you `itemBuilder` gets called with a `snapshot` of a single driver, so with multiple properties. And in that case, the value of the snapshot is indeed a `Map` of values.

---

The most likely solution is to change your data structure to match what you have under `Drivers` - so add an extra child level into your JSON, e.g.:

```
"Products": {
  "anboba": {
    "name": "ANBOBA",
    "price": 117,
    "stoke": "In stock",
    "unfild price": 1400
  },
}
```

Now you can create the `FirebaseAnimatedList` on the `Products` node, and you code will work better.

Comment: thank very much for helping me, by the i didnt solve the problem only but you taught me. thank you for your time

Comment: Did you try to apply the solution I describe? What happened? Any error message?

Comment: no , thank god :)